# Connecting to a non-secure LDAP server via PHP on a Secure Domain

Tags: php, apache, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to connect to an ldap server that the client's IT guy says does not have an SSL certificate. This is on a test file on their domain, which has an SSL installed. Let's say the file is at https://client.org/test_LDAP.php

So I use very simple code to connect, which has worked fine with another client just in the past month:

```
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

define("LDAP_SERVER","ldap://name.their.junk");
define("LDAP_BASE","CN=Users,DC=their,DC=junk");

$username = 'CN=Username,'.LDAP_BASE;
$password = "Password";

$ldap = ldap_connect(LDAP_SERVER, 389) or die("Can't connect to LDAP server");

ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) ;

if (ldap_bind($ldap, $username, $password)) {
    ldap_unbind($ldap);
    echo 'OK - Login valid';
} else {
    die(ldap_error($ldap) . ' (' . ldap_errno($ldap) . ')');
}
```

If I am running code from a domain with an SSL installed, does that mean I HAVE to use ldaps and port 636, even if the client's AD server doesn't have a Certificate? I've tried the code with both ports and both ldaps: and ldap: on an unsecured launch domain and also his secured live domain. Nothing seems to work. But he swears the username and password and all of the variables are correct, and told me to use their IP instaed of the hostname (ldap:000.000.000.00 for example).

Am I doing something wrong here?

And yes, I DO have LDAP configured correctly on my server end, because we just were able to do this exact same thing with another client recently.

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you getting any errors? Something in the log? Have you tried watching the attempted connection (tcpdump, etc)

Comment: On my end or his end? I've asked him to check his logs and haven't heard back. What logs of mine should I check?

Comment: You should check your standard logs for your application (php error logs for instance, turn up verbosity of logging for AD if needed), it really comes down to you saying `its not working` and SO users saying `whats not working, what have you tried so far?`.  Logs should be something you review before asking for help, as they often point to an error (if one is logged). This is just a suggestion for better question formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm a noob when it comes to servers so I just blanked on checking any kind of logs. Should have been obvious.

Comment: Nothing in the error logs of use. From what I'm seeing, it shouldn't matter if the domain your code is on is an SSL or not. His server is either blocking the site or there is some setting on my end that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to perform the searches on Windows 2003 Server Active Directory or above, it seems that you have to set the LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS option to 0:

```
ldap_connect(..) 
ldap_set_option ($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0); 
ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3); 
ldap_bind(..)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me yet. The version he says he is running is Windows 2003 Server x64 SP2 if that means anything. It was worth a shot though, thanks.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and mark this as the correct answer as there is nothing else that can be done until he gives me more information about the server. I'm completely shooting in the dark as to what they have, and I think that it's still a firewall issue that is not letting our server through.

Comment: Why don' you use wireShark to see what happened on the network.

Comment: Never heard of it. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: OK I have WireShark open and NO idea what I'm doing ... oh boy